# Match a string with array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am looping through an array and again i am looping those values one by one to match it with string and if the whole given string matches will the whole element of array they i should print that string but it is not working

```
public class find
{
string[] inputs = {"Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401","Hi there should"};
string store_tran1 = "1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401"

foreach(var store in stores){

                        List<string> outputs = new List<string>();
foreach (var input in inputs)
                        {
                            outputs.AddRange((new String(input.ToCharArray()
                                .Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == ' ')
                                .ToArray()).Split(' ')));
                        }
foreach (var output in outputs)
                            {



                                //string sto = store.ToString ();
                                //Console.Write (output+"\n");
                                bool store_match_check_1 = Regex.IsMatch (store_tran1, @""+Regex.Escape (output)+"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                                if (store_match_check_1 == true) {
                                    //string store_match_check1 = store_match_check_1.Groups [1].Value;

                                     res = true;

                                } else {
                                    store_array_check.Add ("one");
                                    res = false;
                                }


                            }


} 
}
```

Expected output:

```
Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 9040
```

How could i get this woking

Comment: Why use regex when you can simply use the string Contains() method?

Comment: Please fix your indenting to make it easier on us.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just

```
var inputs = new[] { "Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401", "Hi there should" };
var store_tran1 = "1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401";
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    if (input.Contains(store_tran1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

(and if you need you can always ignore case by calling `ToLower()` or calling `Trim()` to remove whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is removing the commas from the input strings, therefore you won't get any matches.

If you really want to remove all non-alphanumeric chars + commas, you could use LINQ like so:

```
var inputs = new[] {"Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401","Hi there should"};
var store_tran1 = "1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401";
inputs.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"^\s*|[^\w\s,]+|\s*$", ""))
      .Where(s => s.Contains(store_tran1))
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

The regex will also trim whitespace from the beginning and end of the input string.

[C# demo](https://repl.it/CTl5/1).

Comment: You shouldn't use `.ForEach()` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: @aloisdg I did it to stay in the LINQ mindset as a simple one-liner. I agree that wrapping it in a foreach block would have been nicer, and also more efficient.